# Can we pass C++ object into Lua scrips

Tags: lua

I want to pass a C++ object to Lua and use the same object in Lua. I have seen example of creating C++ objects in Lua and use them. But I want to do like this below.

- Create a C++ object in C++ code
- Pass this to Lua scripts and get some return values.

I have gone through these examples here.

```
http://loadcode.blogspot.sg/2007/02/wrapping-c-classes-in-lua.html
https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/1594905
```

But they are creating C++ objects in Lua and using them in Lua scripts.
can you please give some pointers.

Comment: You deal them as pointers. Did you read [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/)? It has several chapters on the subject, and with the examples you've got it should be ok.

Comment: There is no way to "create them in Lua".

Answer (score 2):

Given that you did read some userdata manuals, it is very easy to achieve that. The only diference is that in regular ud manual they create objects in Lua function and you already have an object. Just push new userdata of pointer size and set it's metatable to Lua class's metatable (which you prepared anyway).

```
void **ud;
ud = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(*ud));
*ud = object; // existing

luaL_getmetatable(L, tname);
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

// ud at top of stack

lua_setglobal(L, "foo");
```

Where tname is your Lua-side classes metatable name.

Comment: You are missing some sort of type casting.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to use the objects within Lua (just pass them on to C++), you can wrap them as a lightuserdata (see [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_pushlightuserdata)) from C++, and later just pop it (you may want to check if it [is_lightuserdata](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_islightuserdata) before).